# click event on each button of a class (chess viewer)

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time writing here. I am new to programming and here I am learning a lot of things!

Now, I want write this: for each clicked element of a class create a var with nextSibling's text and show it somewhere. The following code is for sure full of error, but it is what i thought:

```
//wants to create an accessible variable (even out the function)
//from a sibling element's text.
$(".games").click(function(){
myVar = this.next("p").html;})
```

the HTML situation is this:

```
<button class="games">GAME ONE</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 1</p>
<button class="games">GAME TWO</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 2</p>
<div id="show"> I will show the content of paragraphs here if one of the two buttons is clicked</div>
```

I thank everybody because - I repeat - I am learning a lot here.

### EDIT

Thanks everybody for the answers. I am trying something related to your suggestions, but i think the problem should be another because actually I am working with chessJS and chessboardJS to make a page where show the moves of a chess game in a chessboard. But, when I try to say that myVar (where there is the moves list to pass to the chessJS function `load_pgn`) is the content of one id like this:

```
<p id="theGame">1. e4 e5</p>

// myVar contains the moves list
var myVar = $("#theGame").html();

Chess().load_pgn(myVar);
```

all works fine, but I cannot make it work by saying that: for each clicked element (of a class, maybe) myVar is the html value of the clicked element. Furthermore in the console I receive an error that says that `pgn_replace is not a function`.

```
<p class="someGames">1. e4 d5 2 Nf3 Nc6</p>
<p class="someGames">1.d4 e5</p>
```

Maybe I explained the fact a bit bad. this is it. Thank you again for the answers.

## FINAL EDIT

Thanks to your answers and other discussions on the site I managed to find a solution to take the text of one element of a class and store in a var with the following code:

```
$('.class').click(function(){
this.textContent = $(this).html();
var myVar = $(this).html();})`
```

Thank you!

Comment: `var myVar = this.next("p").text()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
const button = document.querySelector(".games")
button.addEventListener('click', () => {

  myText = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'your text : I will show the content of paragraphs here if one of the two buttons is clicked ' 
) 

<button class="games">GAME ONE</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 1</p>
<button class="games">GAME TWO</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 2</p>
<div id="show"> <p> I will show the content of paragraphs here if one of the two buttons is clicked  </p></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function buttonClick(button){
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=button.innerHTML
}
```

```html
<button class="games" onclick="buttonClick(this)">GAME ONE</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 1</p>
<button class="games" onclick="buttonClick(this)">GAME TWO</button><p> THESE ARE THE DETAILS OF THE GAME 2</p>
<div id="show"> I will show the content of paragraphs here if one of the two buttons is clicked</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).